# How to enforce type when using point free notation

Tags: haskell, pointfree

Hello how can you enforce `GHC`  type for functions such as `Data.Text.read` or the `=~` operator from `Text.Regex.Posix` when composing methods?

example:
`a=["1.22","3.33","5.55"]`

Without point free:
`b= map (\x-> read x ::Double) a`

How to enforce a type for `read` with point free notation ?

`b=map read::Double a`  or 
 `b= map (read . f1 .f2 .f3... . fn )::Double  a`  (when composing methods) 
 where `f1 , f2 ...fn` are methods

Or better how do you specify the `read` type when it belongs in a chain of methods ,**BUT** not at the end of the chain !  :

`b=map (f2 . read . f1 ) a`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way in modern Haskell is with a [type application](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#visible-type-application).

```
Prelude> :set -XTypeApplications 
Prelude> map (read @Double) ["1.22","3.33","5.55"]
[1.22,3.33,5.55]
Prelude> map (read @Int) ["1.22","3.33","5.55"]
[*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

This works because `read` has the signature

```
read :: ∀ a . Read a => String -> a
```

and therefore `read @Double` specialises `a ~ Double` and thus

```
read @Double :: String -> Double
```

Comment: FWIW I'm not a fan of this extension, so at least one person disagrees this is "The best way..." ;)

Comment: You wouldn't care to explain why you don't like it?

Comment: sure,  sorry: 1) suddenly class constraints stop being a set (the ordering matters; do I now have to worry about re-ordering constraints in my own libraries (imagine my editor automatically alphabetizes them) to stop breakage for users who choose to use type application? Might it even cause bugs that pass the typechecker? I'm honestly not sure).  2) Reuse of `@` for some totally unrelated meaning  3) applying a function to a type doesn't really make sense (I think this is a GHC internal implementation detail (dictionary passing) leaking upwards).  It might be I have wrong ideas about it though

Comment: With 1) you definitely have a point. 2) and 3) don't seem that critical to me.

Comment: @jberryman: #1 is at least no worse than other languages like C++ where you always write explicit quantifiers and their order matters. Order will be important for Dependent Haskell too, since you can’t freely move pi types around like `forall`s. Explicit quantifiers also have the advantage of enabling `ScopedTypeVariables` without changing a signature. Honestly, it seems a bit silly in retrospect that Haskell imposed lexical restrictions to differentiate type constructors & variables just to avoid `forall` (or sigils like OCaml’s `'`)—`@` would’ve been a perfect ASCII substitute for `∀`, too!

Comment: @JonPurdy I'm not sure we'd settle for “at least no worse than C++” in Haskell... I tend to agree, it would have been fine if we'd always had mandatory explicit quantors, but I also agree with Brandon that it was nice that _order_ of quantors used to not matter. But don't know if it would even be possible to retain that in Dependent Haskell.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Haha, fair, I only used C++ as an example since it’s the only one off the top of my head where you regularly partially apply type arguments. Explicit quantifiers are the norm in every imperative language with generics.

Answer (score 3):

`read` has type `String -> a`, so `read x` has type `a`. Just like forcing `read x` to have type `Double` instead of `a` with `read x :: Double`, you can force `read` to have type `String -> Double` instead:

```
b = map (read :: String -> Double) a
```

Comment: So if i have a chain of composed methods `map ( f1 . read . f2 ) a` i could say :        `map ( f2 . read::t0->t1 . f0 ) a ` where `f0::t0` and `read::t1` ?

Comment: Probably not, because `read . f0` doesn't really make sense if `f0` isn't a function that returns a `String`. You can't make wholesale changes to the type of `read`; you can only specialize its type.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian With appropriate parentheses, that is syntactically correct: `map (f2 . (read :: t0 -> t1) . f0) a`. That's likely to be a type error except in some very special circumstances where the context constrains `t0` and `t1` a lot, though.